# Entropy Inequality

Tags: inequality, entropy

I have very hard time to prove  the following inequality or to show a contradiction.

$H(X_1,X_2,X_3) + H(X_1,X_2,X_4)+ H(X_1,X_3,X_4) + H(X_2,X_3,X_4) \leq  3(H(X_1,X_2) + H(X_3,X_4))$

The problem is I don't know how to approach the solution.

I would appreciate for any help.

Comment: Are $X_1, X_2...$ random variables?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Note that $H(X,Y) \leq H(X) + H(Y)$.

$$
H(X_1, X_2, X_3) \leq H(X_1, X_2) + H(X_3)\\
H(X_1, X_2, X_4) \leq H(X_1, X_2) + H(X_4)\\
H(X_1, X_3, X_4) \leq H(X_3, X_4) + H(X_1)\\
H(X_2, X_3, X_4) \leq H(X_3, X_4) + H(X_2)
$$
Therefore,
$$
LHS \leq 2(H(X_1, H_2) + H(X_3, H_4)) + H(X_1) + H(X_2) + H(X_3) + H(X_4)
$$

Can you find a counter example now?